MOSFET Switch to select between 3 voltage levels
I want to switch/select between 3 voltage supplies (130 V, 105 V and 90 V). I want a fast switch around 1 microsecond fast therefore I am using MOSFETs (I could not find a fast enough mux which can support the high voltage a well). The MOSFETs are planned to be controlled by a microcontroller that will switch the one MOSFET with the corresponding voltage required at that time.
The problem is that I cannot figure out how this circuit would look like. Mainly how the output (Vout) of the 3 MOSFETs will be connected to the 1 output device/load (power amplifier). The solutions I have till now gives different/wrong (subtracted) voltage at the output node.

I have the pulse signal for simulation ppurpose only. The output looks like the picture below. The switches work as intended but the Vout is dropped to 90V in all cases. The first two pulses should be 130V, the next two 105V and the last two 90V.


Welcome! Please show your schematic which isn't working as intended and we can help you from there. What's your load?

You have to be aware that the N-channel mosfet you are using have a body-diode that start to conduct in the cases you have 105V and 130V. You would need a two mosfets in back-to-back for this to work.
